# How to connect my computer with Xilinx Ultrascale FPGA

Tags: fpga, xilinx, http-live-streaming, vivado

I'm a novice in FPGA programming, 
I have synthetize a simple matrix-matrix multiplication written in C++ with Xilinx Vivado HLS and I generate the bitstream with Xilinx SDSoC tool and I obtained the following files:

```
sd_card
-- _sds
--- _p0.bin
-- matrixMultiplication.elf
-- BOOT.BIN
-- image.ub
```

I have copied this folder entirely in the sd card of the FPGA. Finally for launching the software I have tried to connect my pc with FPGA through an USB A to micro-USB B cable connected to UART port of the FPGA, but my pc seems not seeing the virtual serial port where FPGA is connected (I have tried with Ubuntu and Windows) and I can't start a serial comunication..
Perhaps I need to install some drivers for USB-UART interface?
Thanks

Comment: yes you need drivers to work with serial-port of US+

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/install/ug1033-cp210x-usb-uart-install.pdf), you can find the installation guide for using UART on the ULTRASCALE+.
After, when launch GtkTerm (for example), choose:

Configuration -> Port ->

1. Port: /dev/ttyUSB0
2. Baud Rate: 115200

This is enough for the default configuration of systems autamatically generated by SDSoC. 
Plase consider another way: to use the eth and a ssh connection (my favorite way to connect with other system): sometime the UART can be a big source of trouble.